# How to write a single query to run some retrospective aggregation when time window is different for every row?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am writing some SQL queries to create a dataset for customer churn predictions based on historical service data. Some of the services date back years ago. Small percentage of them churned at some time in the past while others ended up getting renewed. Some of the attributes are based on aggregation of the services that were active when each of the services was active. For example, I want to find out how many total services were active that was under the same account when an individual account was active.

```
| account_no | service_no | InstallationDate | BillingStopDate | ExtractDate | Churn |
|------------|------------|------------------|-----------------|-------------|-------|
| A1         | S1         | 2018-01          | 2019-03         | 2019-02     | 1     |
| A2         | S2         | 2016-05          | 2020-04         | 2020-03     | 0     |
| A1         | S3         | 2018-07          | 2019-07         | 2019-06     | 0     |
| A1         | S4         | 2016-11          | 2021-03         | 2021-02     | 0     |
| A1         | S5         | 2018-01          | 2019-01         | 2018-12     | 1     |
| A2         | S6         | 2019-01          | 2021-08         | 2021-07     | 1     |
```

The total active services for service `S1` and `S3` under the same account `A` are 4 and 2 respectively because they have different `ExtractDate`. I am currently running SQL query with Python wrapper with `account_no` and `extractDate` as input arguments. And then loop through the whole dataset and run the queries for each row

```
def stats_per_account(conn, account, till_date):
    query = """select count(distinct ServiceNo) from ServicesAll 
               where AccountNo = '{0}' and 
               InstallationDate < '{1}' and
               (BillingStopDate is NULL or BillingStopDate >= '{2}')""".format(account, till_date, till_date)
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
       
    return row

sno = []
ano = []
svc = []

for _, row in tqdm(iter_df.iterrows(), total=iter_df.shape[0]):

    cnt = stats_per_account(conn, row['AccountNo'], row['ExtractDate'])
    sno.append(row['ServiceNo'])
    ano.append(row['AccountNo'])
    svc.append(cnt[0])
```

Since the queries are run one after another sequentially for each row in the dataset. It is very time consuming. I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Maybe a single query for all the rows altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough example you might be able to follow.  I use a `WITH clause` to provide the set of parameters to apply, but you could also store this in a base table to use in the `JOIN`.

If you have an algorithmic way to generate the sets of parameters, that could be used in a derived table or CTE term to provide as many sets as you wish.  We could even use recursive behavior, if your database supports it.

A list of date ranges and list of accounts could easily be used to generate sets of parameters.

The data:

```
SELECT * FROM ServicesAll;

+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------+
| account_no | service_no | InstallationDate | BillingStopDate | ExtractDate | Churn |
+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------+
| A1         | S1         | 2018-01-01       | 2019-03-01      | 2019-02-01  |     1 |
| A2         | S2         | 2016-05-01       | 2020-04-01      | 2020-03-01  |     0 |
| A1         | S3         | 2018-07-01       | 2019-07-01      | 2019-06-01  |     0 |
| A1         | S4         | 2016-11-01       | 2021-03-01      | 2021-02-01  |     0 |
| A1         | S5         | 2018-01-01       | 2019-01-01      | 2018-12-01  |     1 |
| A2         | S6         | 2019-01-01       | 2021-08-01      | 2021-07-01  |     1 |
+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------+
```

Here's an approach which generates lists of accounts and date ranges to derive the sets of parameters to apply, and then applies them all in the same query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE accounts (account_no) AS ( SELECT DISTINCT account_no FROM ServicesAll)
   , startDate (start_date)          AS ( SELECT current_date - INTERVAL '5' YEAR )
   , ranges  (start_date, end_date, n) AS (
          SELECT start_date, start_date + INTERVAL '6' MONTH, 1 FROM startDate UNION ALL
          SELECT start_date + INTERVAL '6' MONTH
               , end_date   + INTERVAL '6' MONTH, n+1 FROM ranges WHERE n < 8
     )
   , args (p0, p1, p2) AS (
          SELECT account_no, start_date, end_date
            FROM accounts, ranges
     )
SELECT p0, p1, p2, COUNT(DISTINCT service_no)
  FROM ServicesAll, args
 WHERE account_no = args.p0
   AND InstallationDate < args.p1
   AND (BillingStopDate IS NULL OR BillingStopDate >= args.p2)
 GROUP BY p0, p1, p2
;
```

The result:

```
+------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| p0   | p1         | p2         | COUNT(DISTINCT service_no) |
+------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| A1   | 2017-02-17 | 2017-08-17 |                          1 |
| A1   | 2017-08-17 | 2018-02-17 |                          1 |
| A1   | 2018-02-17 | 2018-08-17 |                          3 |
| A1   | 2018-08-17 | 2019-02-17 |                          3 |
| A1   | 2019-02-17 | 2019-08-17 |                          1 |
| A1   | 2019-08-17 | 2020-02-17 |                          1 |
| A1   | 2020-02-17 | 2020-08-17 |                          1 |
| A2   | 2016-08-17 | 2017-02-17 |                          1 |
| A2   | 2017-02-17 | 2017-08-17 |                          1 |
| A2   | 2017-08-17 | 2018-02-17 |                          1 |
| A2   | 2018-02-17 | 2018-08-17 |                          1 |
| A2   | 2018-08-17 | 2019-02-17 |                          1 |
| A2   | 2019-02-17 | 2019-08-17 |                          2 |
| A2   | 2019-08-17 | 2020-02-17 |                          2 |
| A2   | 2020-02-17 | 2020-08-17 |                          1 |
+------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
```

The following SQL provide sets of parameters in the `args` CTE term, and then `JOIN`s with that CTE term in the final query expression.  The key is the `GROUP BY` clause which produces a result row for each set of parameters.

```
WITH args (p0, p1, p2) AS (
          SELECT 'A1', '2018-07-02', '2018-07-02' UNION
          SELECT 'A1', '2016-11-02', '2016-11-02' UNION
          SELECT 'A2', '2016-11-02', '2016-11-02'
     )
SELECT p0, p1, p2, COUNT(DISTINCT service_no)
  FROM ServicesAll, args
 WHERE account_no = args.p0
   AND InstallationDate < args.p1
   AND (BillingStopDate IS NULL OR BillingStopDate >= args.p2)
 GROUP BY p0, p1, p2
;
```

Result:

```
+----+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| p0 | p1         | p2         | COUNT(DISTINCT service_no) |
+----+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| A1 | 2016-11-02 | 2016-11-02 |                          1 |
| A1 | 2018-07-02 | 2018-07-02 |                          4 |
| A2 | 2016-11-02 | 2016-11-02 |                          1 |
+----+------------+------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I like the idea but there is one problem. I can probably chain the `SELECT...UNION` statements within the CTE programmatically from the input dataframe. However there are usually tens of thousands of rows in that input dataframe. If I append everything together it is probably going to exceed the length limit for SQL query.  How would I change the query and use a derived table instead?

Comment: I'd suggest, if you can, to generate a list of values for each parameter and then generate combinations, as needed, programmatically.  For instance, decide on some set of ranges you want and generate those ranges.  Generate the list of accounts and then cross join that with your generated list of date ranges, then apply that as shown above, all done in one query. The size of that query should be relatively small.  The `UNION` was just a hard-coded way to show how sets of parameters can be processed in one query.

Comment: @ddd I've added a more dynamic example, which generates ranges and accounts and then derives the sets of parameters to apply, then applies the algorithm to those sets all in one query.  This is the approach I'd probably use.